# What is the process for getting a ZAV Certificate on your own for Germany?

Tags: visa, germany, citizenship, schengen

I am an Indian undergraduate student in my 4th year. I have been accepted for an internship in a German University. I applied for a short term Schengen visa (Guest Scientist / Visiting Scholar) at the German Embassy in New Delhi.I received a call from German Embassy a few days later asking for a ZAV certificate. My Prof. stays very busy. It would be helpful to know more about the ZAV and its application procedure.

What do I need to do to get a ZAV certificate from Germany?

Comment: Have you already done some research yourself? What did you find and why is that information not satisfactory?

Answer (score 1):

You first have to contact the **Immatrikulationsamt** of that German university. They will contact your German professor's office to fill out the neccessary forms for the [**Immatrikulationsbescheinigung**](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0ahUKEwjsj_um_braAhXGyaQKHYvcA0wQFghRMAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.hs-coburg.de%2Ffileadmin%2Fhscoburg%2FImmatrikulationsbescheinigungKoBy.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1rjXNOOq5VOXWWlisaSfTy) you want from them. There are different kinds of *Immatrikulationsbescheinigung*. Please always tell them you are from India and are invited for an internship, so they pick the correct one.

Second, you send this *Immatrikulationsbescheinigung* to the ZAV, a part of the German employment agency. They will issue you a certificate you may come to Germany and work here. (The German university may offer you to do that step for you.)

Third, send this *ZAV certificate* to the embassy so they can issue a visa.